# how to update image stored on folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a grid-view that displays a projects table with both update and delete options. My problem is with updating the project images. When I update the project and `UploadPhoto.HasFile=false`, this means I am not choosing image. In the `else` statement, I want to get the project image as the default or get the project image. This is my code :

```
 int projectid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

  if (UploadPhoto.HasFile)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        if (UploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" ||
                            UploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.jpg" ||
                            UploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.psd" ||
                            UploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.png" ||
                            UploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.gif")
                        {
                            if (UploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength < 8729744)
                            {
                                string filename = Path.GetFileName(UploadPhoto.FileName);
                                UploadPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath
                                    ("~/ProjectsImages/" + 
                                      projectid + filename));

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    string relativePath = "/ProjectsImages/";
                    var path = Server.MapPath(relativePath);
                    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, projectid + "*");
                    UploadPhoto.FileName = filePaths; //here what i want to do 

                }
// At this line I update the project and UploadPhoto.FileName = null
// This overrides the project image 

                context.Update_Project_Detail(txtProjectName.Text, 
                    txtAreas.Text, 
                    DateTime.Parse(txtEditDate.Text),
                    txtClassification.Value, 
                    UploadPhoto.FileName, projectid);
```

What I want in the `else` statement, is to get the `projectimage` name and assign it to `UploadPhoto.filename`.

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: You don't need to update the existing file. You just need to save the uploaded image with the existing image name. It will overwrite it.